# Optimizing an s:ItemRenderer that contains an mx:LineChart

Tags: apache-flex

The application that I'm developing contains a Spark List control which uses a Spark ItemRenderer that contains an mx:LineChart. With every new item added to the list its redraw time noticeably increases. After adding the 15th item the whole GUI freezes for about 20 seconds to refresh the list.

**What can I do to optimize the item renderer?**

Every time I'm adding a new item to the list I'm creating a new ArrayCollection and passing it to the list.

Inside ChartList.as:

```
override protected function commitProperties():void {
    super.commitProperties();
    _itemRenderer = new ClassFactory(ChartListItemRenderer);
    list.itemRenderer = _itemRenderer; //list is a skin part
    list.dataProvider = _data; //list is of type s:List
}
```

Indise ChartListItemRenderer.mxml:

```
<sc:ScenarioChart leftAxisData="data.series}"
                  bottomAxisData="{_period}"/>
```

Inside ScenarioChart:

```
override protected function commitProperties():void {
    super.commitProperties();

    chart.dataProvider = _leftAxisData;
    bottomAxis.dataProvider = _bottomAxisData;
}
```

Comment: Could you post some code ? First of all, you may not need to recreate the whole ArrayCollection since it is specifically made to dispatch events when new items are added or removed. You may cause unnecessary redraw of your ItemRenderers. Also, check that your list has its property `useVirtualLayout` set to `true`. Finally, try to profile your ItemRenderer/LineChart and see if you can optimize it.

Comment: well this statement: " Every time I'm adding a new item to the list I'm creating a new ArrayCollection and passing it to the list" you shouldn't be doing. You should be calling collection.addItem(newItem).  and using collection.refresh() to force updates.  That one step may improve thing significantly.  Also posting some code here would help so we can see exactly what you are doing and try to help.

Comment: Will post code on monday

Comment: Your code does not look right. Usually the place to specify an itemrenderer or setting a dataprovider is not in commitProperties, but again, this is a very cursory look in the larger scheme of things. Run profiler to see if your chart is being drawn more times than it should (Ideally it should be drawn once per rendered item)